# Paraview wind velocity does not match cloud movement

Tags: paraview

I was visualising my wind velocity using glyphs and cloud water content at the same time. However, I notice that the direction where the clouds move do not match the direction the glyphs pointing.

Below are the steps how I create the output:
The data is a netcdf file with wind variable array "ua" (eastward_wind_speed), "va" (northward_wind_speed), and "wa" (wind_vertical_velocity).

1. I used a cell_data_to_point_data filter to convert them into point data.
2. Then I combined these 3 arrays using a Paraview calculator with the equation iHat*ua + jHat*va + kHat*wa.
3. Then do a glyph filter to visualise the wind velocity.

The problem is, the clouds are moving to the left(east), which does not match where the glyphs are pointing at (south).

What would be the possible reason for this error?

TIA

Update:
For anyone that might have the same problem:

Just solved the problem and the glyphs make much more sense now.

1. Switched off the spherical coordinate
2. Transform filter to scaled down the vertical components

Then do the contour filter and glyph filter as usual.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider.

1. Some weather agencies use a convection of wind direction from which is blowing. However there are agencies that have a wind direction to which is blowing.
2. Probably you are not using the wind direction at the same height as the clouds.

Comment: I am visualising the glyphs at the same height as the clouds. For the first point, I am not quite sure what you mean. Could you details a bit more?

Comment: For the first point I mean that some weather agencies have a 180° of rotation in wind direction.

Comment: Try to plot wind against pressure to check if there is any rotation.